# How to enable cache for getServerSideProps?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

We have few pages and components as server side rendering.

We were trying to use cache for few API responses.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
   const res = await getRequest(API.home)
   return {
     props: {
       "home": res?.data?.result
     },
   }
}
```

Next.js version is 11.1.

Here can someone please suggest how can we implement cache?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `Cache-Control` header inside `getServerSideProps` using `res.setHeader`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // Add whatever `Cache-Control` value you want here
    context.res.setHeader(
        'Cache-Control',
        'public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59'
    )
    const res = await getRequest(API.home)
    return {
        props: {
            home: res?.data?.result
        }
    }
}
```

Setting a `Cache-Control` value only works in production mode, as the header will be overwritten in development mode.

See [Caching with Server-Side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#caching-with-server-side-rendering-ssr) documentation for more details.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately it appears that it only works with Vercel and other edge providers. :-(

Comment: @AdamShand If you mean `stale-while-revalidate`  then yes - only some providers support it. However, you don't have to use it in the `Cache-Control` value, it was merely an example. Caching can still work without it.

Comment: Hrm.  I tried the example in the documentation, deployed to a docker container and it didn't seem to work (or I'm misunderstanding what's supposed to happen), the rendered time updates with every page refresh.

 <https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/ssr-caching/pages/index.js>

Comment: @AdamShand I feel this needs more details to get to the bottom of it, which won't be possible through comments alone. I'd recommend creating a new detailed question for the issue you're having.

Comment: @AdamShand Also, make sure you don't have caching disabled in the dev tools if you're checking requests through it.

Comment: @AdamShand s-maxage is for CDN or proxy, use max-age for web browsers. Notice three places that contents are cached, browsers, cdn and proxy.

Comment: I've used this to remove caching to fetch new data instead of page reload:

`context.res.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");`

Comment: if a cache is set like this, does this mean any code inside getServerSideProps will not be run if we are inside the cache time value?

Comment: @alexr89 The `Cache-Control` header is used by the browser/CDN. If within the cache time value, the request to the Next.js server will not even happen - the cached version will be served instead. So yes - any code inside `getServerSideProps` will not run for that specific request.

Comment: don't know why, but i am getting error  - `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`