# Can Next.js return a 304 Not Modified status for an SSR page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

It is obvious that Next.js returns a 304 Not Modified HTTP status for SSG pages, but can it do it for pages that were rendered in real-time?

Going the other way around, does Next.js return an ETag header when an SSR page is initially requested?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to enable cache for getServerSideProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71333002/how-to-enable-cache-for-getserversideprops)?

Answer (score 5):

As of Next.js v13 (at least) is seems you can, but you have to set the status code, and `ETag`/`Last-Modified` and check for incoming `If-None-Match`/`If-Modified-Since` headers yourself.

Mock code:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {}
  const { req, res } = ctx;

  if (shouldReturnNotModified(req)) {
    res.statusCode = 304;
    return { props: {} };
  }
  
  res.setHeader('ETag', generateETag(req));
  return { 
    props: await fetchAllTheProps(req),
  };
}

// This is not rendered if the `res.statusCode` is 304
export default function MyPage (props) {
  return (
    <div>
      Render the page's 200 OK response 
      using all the props
    </div>
  );
}
```

The only thing Next.js really helps with is to skip rendering the response body if it notices you've set `res.statusCode` to 304.

None of this is officially documented. (Searching for "304" in the Nextjs docs returns 0 results.)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your headers to add caching on your page. Read more at: https://nextjs.org/docs/going-to-production#caching

Comment: Link is not found. Use this instead: [https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/production-checklist#caching](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/production-checklist#caching)